# Redux: Does this count as mutating state?

Tags: javascript, angular, redux

Using Redux within Angular2 (NgRedux) for updating/setting an order entry. Is it ok to mutate a proxy variable, then object.assign it to state?

In my data reducer:

```
case DataActions.UPDATE_ORDER:
  var updatedItem
  var updatedState = state.orders
  for(var i = 0; i < state.orders.length; ++i) {
    if(state.orders[i]['key'] === action.payload.key) {
      updatedItem = state.orders[i]
      updatedItem.name = action.payload.name
      updatedItem.items = action.payload.items
    }
  }
  updatedState[i] = updatedItem
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    orders: updatedState
  })
```

Comment: I'm using (my package) [flatcopy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatcopy) for all my reducers, and copy my objects/arrays before mutating them. To see that's it's a copy I prefix the vars with `_`, so any assignment has to have an underscore var on the left side (also see the readme of flatcopy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "proxy variable" is just another reference to the same object, so yes, you *are* directly mutating the items in that array.

In order to correctly do immutable updates, each level of nesting should be copied.  The Redux docs give examples of both common mistakes, and how to do this correctly, in [Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html).

Comment: Yes! Thank you kind sir. I knew something felt off.

Comment: BTW, immerjs does a great job helping on the state updates and is incredibly simple to use (https://github.com/immerjs/immer)

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @markerikson for the solution.

I went with the documentation's advice and used the dotProp library. This worked:

```
npm install dot-prop-immutable
...
var dotProp = require('dot-prop-immutable');
...
case DataActions.UPDATE_ORDER:
  for(var i = 0; i < state.orders.length; ++i) {
    if(state.orders[i]['key'] === action.payload.key) {
      state = dotProp.set(state, `orders.${i}.name`, action.payload.name)
      state = dotProp.set(state, `orders.${i}.items`, action.payload.items)
    }
  }
  return state
```